# Win7 Task Scheduler Crashes with Error Description "RpcServerUseProtseq:ncacn_ip_tcp"

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

I just installed my fresh Windows 7 and so far are not very happy with it. Much more problems than with Windows Vista.

The latest in a series:
My *Task Scheduler* crashes right at the moment when I boot my system.

When I check the *Event Viewer* it tells me that the scheduler crashes with a critical error:

- EventID: 404
- ErrorDescription: RpcServerUseProtseq:ncacn_ip_tcp
- ResultCode: 1721

I found this entry in TechNet, but there is no "Internet" Key in my registry:
"[Task Scheduler service has encountered RPC initialization error...](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasp/thread/0c438376-1486-4ae4-9847-2de7a8767f27/)"

- Windows 7 Professional (German) x64
- 8GB RAM
- 430GB free space on C:\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the cause of my problem: **Avira AntiVir Premium**

I deinstalled it and now the *Scheduler* seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

I received the following error

> Task Scheduler service has encountered RPC initialization error in "RpcServerUseProtseq:ncacn_ip_tcp". Additional Data: Error Value: 1721.

This prevented Task Scheduler, backup/restore points, defrag and other critical functions from working. It was the Avira Antivirus Premium 2012.

As soon as I uninstalled Avira, the TaskScheduler started working.